# PowerView - Inferred Relationship

Tags: ssas, business-intelligence, powerview

I have a basic star schema as a source for a tabular cube. It has a fact table that has key columns that relates it to a school and student dimension tables (there are others but for the sake of this question let's keep it simple). I've put a single measure called enrollment count

In my BI Model - I have created a relationship between these tables (see diagram below). Note, there is no direct relationship between school and student.

[Basic Model](http://www.dumpt.com/img/viewer.php?file=bxwfgwg993xrfpzh7yz4.jpg)
[image]

I then deploy my solution to SharePoint and create a power view.

I add the School and Student tables and set them as slicers. I then add my measure from the fact table. The behavior I want is when I click on a school, the student list to filter down. This is the behavior I get in PowerPivot but it does not seem to work in PowerView

[PowerView](http://www.dumpt.com/img/viewer.php?file=078r3j5o3rx7637hmsms.png)

My question is..........Is this possible in a PowerView or do I need to create a relationship between school and student?

Thanks in advance

G

Comment: If you put the students in a table rather than as slicers, do you get the desired result?  I think this might be because they are both slicers.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. No that won't give me the desired behaviour. I've had contact with MS and they have confirmed a direct or inferred relationship is required via Many:Many pattern.

Comment: @Gilly If you're still around, could you perhaps add an answer to this question explaining what you've said in the comments here? It might help someone else who has the same question in future. Thanks!